# Apache rewrite rule to map subdomain to subfolder recursively

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, recursion, url-rewriting

I am experimenting a bit with apache rewrite rules to see if my idea is even possible. Thus far I have this working for me:

```
# Dynamic subdomain->subfolder rewrite
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.(.+)\.my-domain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%1/
RewriteRule (.*) /srv/web/%2/www/%1$1
```

This allowes me to use virtual subdomains like a.b.my-domain.tld, which in this case would map to the subfolder a in the document root of virtual host b.my-domain.tld.

What I want to achieve is a recursive solution where I can use a.b.c.my-domain.tld to map to folder b/a of virtual host c.my-domain.tld, or a.b.c.d.my-domain.tld to map to folder c/b/a of virtual host d.my-domain.tld.

I could just add more rules to get two or three levels working, but it would be very cool (and much cleaner) if there was a solution that enabled indefinite levels of recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error it seems like I've found a viable solution. It's not as clean as I have hoped, but I don't think this is possible using only RewriteCond/RewriteRule.

I ended up with using RewriteMap and my config is now:

```
# Dynamic subdomain->subfolder rewrite
RewriteMap rewrite "prg:/etc/apache2/subdomainrewrite.php"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.(.+)\.my-domain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/${rewrite:%1}/
RewriteRule (.*) /srv/web/%2/www/${rewrite:%1}$1
```

And the content of subdomainrewrite.php is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$input = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
while (1) {
  $line = trim(fgets($input));
  echo implode('/', array_reverse(explode('.', $line))) . "\n";
}
```

I'm sure that it's ugly and advised against to do something like this, but it is working as I wanted. So if nothing else it's at least a proof of concept. Please leave a comment if you have any thoughts or improvements to this solution.